# Titanium Studio to Grails imge post

Tags: grails, titanium-mobile

I am trying to POST an image to my grails application and I'm not having much luck.

My titanium code is:

```
function upload(){  
    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onerror = function(e){
        Ti.API.info(picMedia + " : " +message.value);
        Ti.API.info('IN ERROR ' + e.error);
        alert('Sorry, we could not upload your photo! Please try again.');
    };
    xhr.onload = function(){
        Ti.API.info('IN ONLOAD ' + this.status + ' readyState ' + this.readyState);
    };
    xhr.onsendstream = function(e){
        Ti.API.info('ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: ' + e.progress);
    };
    // open the client
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/FYP/Profile/appUploader'); 
    // send the data
    xhr.send({
        media: picMedia,
        message: message.value,
    });

}
```

My grails code is as follows:

```
   def appUploader(){

            println "MEDAI PARAMS: " + params.media
          def f = request.getFile('media') ;
             println "HERE: " + f
           if (request.getFile(params.media).getOriginalFilename()) {
               println     "FROM APP: "      +    request.getFile('myFile').getOriginalFilename()


               return
           }
    }
```

Im getting error from the mobile app and error on the "if" line in the web app.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to post the errors you're getting

Comment: If you try to upload files via ajax, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Are you sure tht you're using `multipart/form-data` content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we had the same problem in one of our apps. The difficulty is that titanium is not really able to handle binary files in that case.

We did the following:

- create base64 encoded string of the image on client side
- post this string to the backend
- decode base64 to image again

We analyzed a lot of network traffic and in most cases titanium tries to send the file but due to javascript its alway converted into some kind of ascii and this is not usable by the server side.